# how I improve the asynchrony in this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, promise

i have the next code in react, it requests information by api in monday.com, then with the answer I make another request for the weather by cities. then I render a climate card for each city found. the problem is that the array "cityWeathers" should have 9 elements, but some calls come 3, in another 5, in another 7, always several. I don't know what the error can be.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {      
      setData: {},
      context:{},
      settings: {},
      myData: { boards: [] },
      cityWeathers:[]
    };     
  }  
 
  componentDidMount() {  
  const getWeather = async () => monday.api('query  { boards( ids : xxxxxxxxxx ) { items { id : name column_values { text }}}}')
                        .then((res) => {  
                          this.setState({myData:res.data});
                          this.state.myData.boards.map((board) => {
                            board.items.map((item) =>{                               
                              fetch(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=${item.column_values[3].text}&aqi=no`)
                              .then((res) => res.json())
                              .then((json) => {                                
                                //console.log(json);
                                let cityWeather ={
                                name: json.location.name,
                                temp_c:json.current.temp_c,
                                temp_f:json.current.temp_f,                          
                                condition: json.current.condition.text,
                                localTime: json.location.localtime,
                                icon: json.current.condition.icon
                              };
                              let cityWeathers = [...this.state.cityWeathers, cityWeather];

                              this.setState({cityWeathers});
                              
                              })
                          })}
                          )
                        }
                      ) 
     getWeather()
  }          
  render(){             
        return(           
            <div className="App">
              <div className="container">
                <div className="row">                  
                  <div className="col-md-4">  
                    {console.log(this.state.cityWeathers.length)}
                     { this.state.cityWeathers.map((city) => 
                      <WeatherCard key={city.name}  className="cards" name={city.name} 
                                  temp_c={city.temp_c} temp_f={city.temp_f} icon={city.icon}
                                  condition={city.condition} localtime={city.localTime} />)
                     }                                       
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            )        
    }
} 


>I request information by api in monday.com, then with the answer I make another request for the weather by cities. then I render a climate card for each city found. the problem is that the array "cityWeathers" should have 9 elements, but some calls come 3, in another 5, in another 7, always several. I don't know what the error can be.
```

Comment: You are using async but never used await

Comment: "*the array "cityWeathers" should have 9 elements*" - how do you know? What is the value of `this.state.myData.boards`? Also you are not handling errors on any of the requests you make.

Comment: the data returned by the api in ".boards" is known in advance. There are 9 names of cities.